# Doubt regarding Leibnitz's Rule for Differentiation under the Integral Sign.

Tags: integration

Definition (As given in my Textbook):

> If the function $\phi(x)$ and $\tau(x)$ are defined on $[a,b]$ and are differentiable at a point $x\in(a,b)$ and $f(x,t)$ is continous, then: $${d\over dx}{\left( \int_{\tau(x)}^{\phi(x)}f(x,t)dt\right)}=\int_{\tau(x)}^{\phi(x)}{\partial\over\partial x}{f(x,t)dt}+\underbrace{\left(d^{\phi(x)}\over dx \right)f^{(x,\phi(x))}-\left(d^{\tau(x)}\over dx \right)f^{(x,\tau(x))}}$$

I don't understand the notation used in the last two terms: what does $d^{\phi(x)}\over dx$ and $f^{(x,\phi(x))}$ mean?Also, I would be grateful if someone could solve a problem using the above defintion.

Comment: Also note that it is not sufficient that $f$ is continuous. What you need is the continuity of $\partial f/\partial x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\red#1{{\color{red}{#1}}}$Looks like some typo in your textbook, we have

> If the function $\phi(x)$ and $\tau(x)$ are defined on $[a,b]$ and are differentiable at a point $x\in(a,b)$ and $f(x,t)$ is continous, then: $${d\over dx}{\left( \int_{\tau(x)}^{\phi(x)}f(x,t)dt\right)}=\int_{\tau(x)}^{\phi(x)}{\partial\over\partial x}{f(x,t)dt}+\underbrace{\left(d\red{\phi(x)}\over dx \right)f\red{(x,\phi(x))}-\left(d\red{\tau(x)}\over dx \right)f\red{(x,\tau(x))}}$$

An example: Let's have a look at 
$$ F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^3} tx \, dt $$
On one hand, we have 
$$ F(x) = \left[\frac{t^2 x}{2}\right]_{x^2 }^{x^3} = \frac 12(x^7-x^5) $$
hence 
$$ F'(x) = \frac 72 x^6 - \frac 52 x^4 $$
We can also use the formula above, with 
$$ f(t,x) = tx, \quad \tau(x)= x^2, \quad \phi(x) = x^3 $$
Giving 
$$ F'(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^3} t\, dt + 3x^2\cdot x\cdot x^3 - 2x \cdot x \cdot x^2 = \frac 12(x^6 - x^4) + 3x^6 - 2x^4 = \frac 72 x^6 - \frac 52 x^4 $$